# How to perform Tukey HSD unconfounded comparisons with adjusted p-value in R or Python

Tags: r, anova

I performed a two-way 2x4 ANOVA and found that the interaction term was significant. Now I'd like to perform Tukey's HSD post hoc testing on the 8 cells. I used the TukeyHSD() function in R and it does all 28 possible cell to cell combinations using a k of 8 for lookup in the Q-table.

Comparing cells within the same columns or rows is relevant to me while diagonal comparisons are not. So there would be 16 comparisons instead of 28. I saw a couple sources calling these unconfounded versus confounded comparisons and they suggested only doing unconfounded comparisons with an adjusted k-value for lookup in the Q-table (https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/brain-and-cognitive-sciences/9-07-statistical-methods-in-brain-and-cognitive-science-spring-2004/lecture-notes/21_anova4.pdf and http://www.real-statistics.com/two-way-anova/follow-up-analyses-for-two-factor-anova/tukey-hsd-after-two-factor-anova/)

I'm wondering if this is a valid thing to do and if so if there is some way to do it conveniently in R.

Comment: Although some people do it, comparing all cells following an interaction is not helpful for understanding the interaction nor is it well justified. You might consider simple effects since the generality of the main effect is in doubt. You might also test the three components of the interaction separately. Regardless, you should start by plotting the effects of the variable with 4 levels separately for the two levels of the other variable.

Answer (score 1):

You might like the **lsmeans** package for this. You can do stuff like:

```
library(lsmeans)
( a.lsm = lsmeans(model, ~ a | b) )
pairs(a.lsm)
```

... and the same thing reversing the factors. If you want all the comparisons considered as one family, use

```
rbind(pairs(a.lsm), pairs(b.lsm))
```

A multivariate $t$ correction is made for the simultaneous tests - which is the right one-step correction.